# Inner Join (Select . From)

Tags: sql

I need to get the last record posted by users.  The following query below would get the information I need if I want if I can do order by before group by

```
select a.client_id, a.client, b.title, b.type, b.created 
  from profile_users a, node b 
 where a.uid = b.uid 
   and b.type = 'event' 
   and a.status=1 
   and a.client_id in (select c.client_id 
                         from profile_users c, follows d 
                        where c.uid = d.followed_id 
                          and d.following_id =3) 
 group by a.client_id 
 order by a.client_id,
          b.created desc
```

I tried rewriting the query using inner join but not getting the desired result. I need to write this query so that I am getting the client_id after checking records on follows table.  I need some assistance to fix this query.

```
select b.client_id, b.client, a.title, a.created
  from node a 
 inner join profile_users b on a.uid=b.uid 
 inner join (select c.client_id
               from profile_users c 
              inner join follows d on c.uid=d.followed_id
              where c.status = 1
                and d.following_id = 3
              order by c.client_id
             ) as X1
```

Comment: add the table name on the second inner join

Comment: @SRIRAM: the second inner join is not missing a table name it's missing a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql "partition by " it will allow you  to sort your records without group by.

http://learnsqlserver.in/2/Partition-By-Clause.aspx

This is best to use over group by.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a co-related subquery in order to determine the last post:

```
select a.client_id, a.client, b.title, b.type, b.created 
  from profile_users a
    join node b on a.uid = b.uid 
 where b.type = 'event' 
   and a.status=1 
   and a.client_id in (select c.client_id 
                         from profile_users c
                           join follows d on c.uid = d.followed_id
                        where d.following_id = 3) 
   and b.created = (select max(n2.created) 
                    from node n2
                    where n2.uid = a.uid)
 order by a.client_id,
          b.created desc
```

I also changed your old-style implicit joins in the where clause to explicit ones using the 'JOIN' keyword.

Comment: Thanks, the revised query helps.  I am still working on it though as the output has all records the person is following and not just the last record.

Comment: The following is the query that worked for me --------             select a.client_id, a.client, b.nid, b.title, b.type, b.created   from profile_users a  join node b on a.uid = b.uid, (select d.uid, d.client_id, d.client, c.created, c.title from node c join profile_users d on c.uid=d.uid join follows e  on d.uid=e.followed_id where c.type ='event' and d.status=1 and e.following_id = 3 order by d.client_id, c.created desc) n2 where b.type = 'event' and a.status=1 and b.uid = n2.uid and b.created = n2.created and b.title =n2.title group by a.client_id